# active state doesn't work for my NavLink but inline style is OK

Tags: reactjs

So the problem is I do something wrong cause active class doesn't work.
Here is what it looks like
[image]

inline style is working perfect but "activeClassName" isn't.
That's my modules.css
[image]

And what I see in browser is
[image]

Comment: If you're using `activeClassName` the prop should always be set, not only when the link is active: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: Did you try `<NavLink activeClassName="active" >` would this work for you?

Comment: @SabrinaLuo I've tried it right now, hasn't helped

Comment: @niQu can you describe it in more details, cause I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Basicly the same as Sabrina was suggesting. The NavLink then only gets active, if the provided link is the current page.

Comment: Does the following work `<NavLink className={isActive => isActive ? "active" : ""} >`?

Comment: @niQu nope, still isn't working

Comment: did you try remove `exact`?

Comment: @SabrinaLuo yep, the result is the same

Comment: Can you update your question to include properly formatted code snippets instead of pictures of code? Images are not searchable or copy/paste-able, and can be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NavLink` API changed a bit in `react-router-dom` v6, there is no longer an `activeClassName` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style"> {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

You can conditionally apply your active class via a `className` prop function, or in the `style` prop function.

```
<NavLink
  className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? s.active : null}
  to={props.buttonName.toLowerCase()}
>
  {props.buttonName}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I really use "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2" but your example didn't help anyway

Comment: @ПавелРодин The interface is straight from the docs, the code example is nearly a copy/paste from the docs. Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how NavLink work with `activeClassName` in v5.x

```js
const NavLink = ReactRouterDOM.NavLink;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const arr = ['a','b','c']
const App = () => <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  {arr.map(s=> 
    <NavLink key={s} to={`/${s}`} activeClassName="active">link {s}</NavLink>
  )}
  </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter >;

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

a.active {
  color: red;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: As Drew Reese mentioned is activeClassName still compatible with RRDv6?

Comment: @ПавелРодин The above example is using `v5.0.0`, as specified in the doc, v6 does not support `activeClassName`. Ref: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink